# Image distortion using PIL vs opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, keras, python-imaging-library

**Edit-** Attaching random pics from Flickr8k Dataset using the same transformations as discussed (can't share the original images - private dataset)

[Output RGB image when loaded using Keras's generator **with PIL arraytoimage transformation**, using the following pre-processing function:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5wiM.png)

```
def myFunc(image):
  image = np.array(image)
  rgb = Image.fromarray(image,mode='RGB')
  return rgb
```

[Output RGB image when loaded using Keras's generator **without PIL arraytoimage transformation** using the following pre-processing function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpW4E.png)

```
def myFunc(image):
  image = np.array(image)
  return image
```

[Output HSV image when loaded using Keras's generator **with PIL arraytoimage transformation**, using the following pre-processing function:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isW2E.png)

```
def myFunc(image):
  image = np.array(image)
  hsv_image = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)
  hsv = Image.fromarray(hsv_image,mode='HSV')
  return hsv
```

[Output HSV image when loaded using Keras's generator **without PIL arraytoimage transformation** using the following pre-processing function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5UXe.png)

```
def myFunc(image):
  image = np.array(image)
  hsv_image = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)
  return hsv_image
```

Generator-

```
testgen=ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=myFunc)
```

I am performing some binary and multi-class classification tasks on a medical image dataset. I am using Keras's ImageDataGenerator and flow_from_directory to load images batch wise. Also, performing on the fly pre-processing and augmentation. There were two things that I have tried -

1. Using opencv for color space conversion and feeding the resulting 3D numpy array to the model
2. Using opencv for color space conversion then converting the resulting 3D numpy array to image using PIL Image module and the appropriate color mode

So, when I load the image via Keras's generator and view it - once using PIL and the other time without using PIL, interestingly enough - PIL Image Module + Keras's generator together completely distort the image. It looks like noise. 
If I simply read the image using opencv and pass it through the preprocessing function - color space conversion with opencv and arraytoimage using PIL - the image returned is not distorted.
Also, if I load the image via Keras's generator and eliminate the PIL arraytoimage conversion step - once again the returned image turns out to be fine.
Somehow, the combination of the generator and PIL's function seems to be distorting the image in unknown ways. This is irrespective of the color space - even RGB image gets distorted if I load it using generator and process it with opencv then PIL.
The most confusing part is - my model's accuracy is dramatically different in both the cases.

This pre-processing function gets me a test accuracy of 95% and above, but completely distorts the image. Feature maps make no sense. (This is when I used the Keras's generator for loading the images)

```
def myFunc(image):
  image = np.array(image)
  hsv_image = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)
  hsv= Image.fromarray(hsv_image,mode='HSV')
  return hsv
```

This pre-processing function gets me a test accuracy of only 75, but it does not distort the image. Feature maps make complete sense.

```
def myFunc(image):
  image = np.array(image)
  hsv_image = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)
  return hsv_image
```

I get far better results for both binary and multi-class classification on both validation and test sets with the distorted noisy images as input, which is clearly wrong since I can't justify my results that way. But it doesn't exactly seem to be a random/wrong transformation - it is giving great results consistently, after changing multiple parameters. 
Is there a way to analyze this accidental transformation? Is there a possibility of some real information preservation thing going on here which is boosting my model's accuracy? I don't want to discard the results without proper analysis. But I am not sure how to go about it! Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: All this with no indication of what the images look like? Kindly share your images in their native form so we can get an idea of what's going on.

Comment: @MarkSetchell added images

Comment: OpenCV and Numpy read images as BGR not RGB. So if you load it by either, then you need to specify the conversion from BGR to HSV as `cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)`. I believe PIL reads and uses images as RGB, but I am not positive of that, since I do not use it much and do not recall.

Comment: @fmw42 But I am not loading the images using opencv, I am loading it using the generator. Generator's default mode is RGB. Also, just tried using the BGR convention - that is not working either (one again giving me a distorted and noisy output with PIL).